# one of the firebase realtime database instance not authenticated when initialized for multiple database in web javascript

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

in web i have firebase project with two database instances in the same project / app

***after successful login with firebase auth;***

the second database reference seems to be non authenticated and thus the database access fail; with `auth != null` in rules.

if i replace the second database url in config object and put default database url in config2 the second database than starts to work fine authenticated but old database fails with database access rule `auth != null`

How can i use both database in web javascript code without anyone having the above issue ?

Is the initialisation done correctly ?

[image]

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

Should be documented properly in firebase documentation for Auth in web
but unfortunately its not for this question.

So the firebase auth instances are maintained separately including the auth callback

So i had to do like bellow

```
await firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(_ths.form.email, _ths.form.password);
await firebase.app('app2').auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(_ths.form.email, _ths.form.password);


let authPromises = [];
authPromises.push(new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
    if (user) resolve(user);
  });
}));

authPromises.push(new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
  firebase.app('app2').auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
    if (user) resolve(user);
  });
}));

Promise.all(authPromises).then(async(users)=>{
     // ....
    let oldDbInstance = firebase.database();
    let newDbInstance = firebase.database(app2);
});
```

Phew!!!